# Why are my federal and state income tax deductions wildly different between paychecks?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I got a new job. My first paycheck was for only one week of work since I started during a pay period. These are the figures:

```
Gross Pay: 2395.83
Federal Income Deduction: 151.62
California State Income Deduction: 90.63
```

My second paycheck was for 10 days of work so I figured the deductions would simply be double but they are significantly more. These are the figures:

```
Gross Pay: 4791.67
Federal Income Deduction: 495.79
California State Income Deduction: 335.30
```

Both paychecks are using `3` for the federal and state exemptions. Can you please help me figure out why those numbers are so much higher for simply another week of work?

Comment: Keep in mind that every time you change jobs, you should probably use the IRS' online [tax calculator](https://apps.irs.gov/app/withholdingcalculator/) to make sure that you'll actually be okay. Just plug in a few details, and you'll get an estimate and advice for altering your W4, if necessary.

Answer (score 36):

Since you get paid biweekly, tax withholding is based on multiplying your pay by 26 pay periods a year. Your withholding for the first paycheck was based on the assumption that you’re making $62,000 a year, and for the second, $125,000 a year. Since we have progressive tax rates, the tax is far more than double.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where can I look up the tax rates?

Comment: 2018 Federal tax rates: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf (page 7). 2018 withholding tables: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/n1036.pdf

Comment: @zeckdude Also, https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2017-California-Tax-Rates-and-Exemptions.shtml